# Grouping and finding identical elements in list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, grouping

I have several lists of tuples like these ones (they represent coordinates):

```
a = [(100,100), (50,60)]
b = [(100,50), (50,60)]
c = [(100,100), (20,60)]
d = [(70,100), (50,10)]
e = [(100,80), (70,100)]
```

I would like to know how to efficiently manage them for finding the identical values and then storing the whole list in a separate list.

Since they are coordinates, the X and Y for every tuple could not be the same in another tuple (i.e. same X, but different Y).

For the above example, I would like to finally have something like this (as a list, but also in a more efficient way if it is possible):

```
new_list1 = [a, b, c]
new_list2 = [d, e]
```

Is there a more efficient way to get this result without a one-to-one parsing between the several lists?

Comment: Why are `a`, `b` and `c` grouped together i.e. what determines in which group a list of tuples ends up?

Comment: @Cleb See each list as a line (because it has 2 points). Well, I would try to build something like a "chain", i.e. there will be at least two shared points in it. For example, for the `new_list1`, `a` and `b` share `(50,60)`, while `a` and `c` share `(100,100)`. I hope it will be clearer by now.

Comment: But in `d` there is also a `(50,60)` tuple. Why is it in list2 and not in list1?

Comment: @Cleb sorry, it was a typo! I edited the question, now it should be ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's a `numpy`tastic vectorised approach. Seems reasonably fast. Not thoroughly tested though. It explicitl assumes each list has two tuples and each tuple 2 coordinates.

```
import time
import numpy as np

def find_chains_nmp(lists):
    lists = np.asanyarray(lists)
    lists.shape = -1,2
    dtype = np.rec.fromrecords(lists[:1, :]).dtype
    plists = lists.view(dtype)
    lists.shape = -1, 2, 2
    uniq, inv = np.unique(plists, return_inverse=True)
    uniqf = uniq.view(lists.dtype).reshape(-1, 2)
    inv.shape = -1, 2
    to_flip = inv[:, 0] > inv[:, 1]
    inv[to_flip, :] = inv[to_flip, ::-1].copy()
    sl = np.lexsort(inv.T[::-1])
    sr = np.lexsort(inv.T)
    lj = inv[sl, 0].searchsorted(np.arange(len(uniq)+1))
    rj = inv[sr, 1].searchsorted(np.arange(len(uniq)+1))
    mask = np.ones(uniq.shape, bool)
    mask[0] = False
    rooted = np.zeros(uniq.shape, int)
    l, r = 0, 1
    blocks = [0]
    rblocks = [0]
    reco = np.empty_like(lists)
    reci = 0
    while l < len(uniq):
        while l < r:
            ll = r
            for c in rooted[l:r]:
                if (rj[c]==rj[c+1]) and (lj[c]==lj[c+1]):
                    continue
                connected = np.r_[inv[sr[rj[c]:rj[c+1]], 0],
                                  inv[sl[lj[c]:lj[c+1]], 1]]
                reco[reci:reci+lj[c+1]-lj[c]] = uniqf[inv[sl[lj[c]:lj[c+1]], :]]
                reci += lj[c+1]-lj[c]
                connected = np.unique(connected[mask[connected]])
                mask[connected] = False
                rr = ll + len(connected)
                rooted[ll:rr] = connected
                ll = rr
            l, r = r, rr
        blocks.append(l)
        rblocks.append(reci)
        if l == len(uniq):
            break
        r = l + 1
        rooted[l] = np.where(mask)[0][0]
        mask[rooted[l]] = 0
    return blocks, rblocks, reco, uniqf[rooted]


# obsolete
def find_chains(lists):
    outlist = []
    outinds = []
    outset = set()
    for j, l in enumerate(lists):
        as_set = set(l)
        inds = []
        for k in outset.copy():
            if outlist[k] & as_set:
                outset.remove(k)
                as_set |= outlist[k]
                inds.extend(outinds[k])
        outset.add(j)
        outlist.append(as_set)
        outinds.append(inds + [j])
    outinds = [outinds[j] for j in outset]
    del outset, outlist
    result = [[lists[j] for j in k] for k in outinds]
    return result, outinds


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = [(100,100), (50,60)]
    b = [(100,50), (50,60)]
    c = [(100,100), (20,60)]
    d = [(70,100), (50,10)]
    e = [(100,80), (70,100)]

    lists = [a, b, c, d, e]
    print(find_chains(lists))



    lists = np.array(lists)
    tblocks, lblocks, lreco, treco = find_chains_nmp(lists)


    coords = np.random.random((12_000, 2))
    pairs = np.random.randint(0, len(coords), (12_000, 2))
    pairs = np.delete(pairs, np.where(pairs[:, 0] == pairs[:, 1]), axis=0)
    pairs = coords[pairs, :]
    t0 = time.time()
    tblocks, lblocks, lreco, treco = find_chains_nmp(pairs)
    t0 = time.time() - t0
    print('\n\nproblem:')
    print('\n\ntuples {}, lists {}'.format(len(coords), len(pairs)))
    if len(pairs) < 40:
        for k, l in enumerate(pairs):
            print('[({:0.6f}, {:0.6f}), ({:0.6f}, {:0.6f})]    '
                  .format(*l.ravel()), end='' if k % 2 != 1 else '\n')
    print('\n\nsolution:')
    for j, (lists, tuples) in enumerate(zip(
            np.split(lreco, lblocks[1:-1], axis=0),
            np.split(treco, tblocks[1:-1], axis=0))):
        print('\n\ngroup #{}: {} tuples, {} list{}'.format(
            j + 1, len(tuples), len(lists),
            's' if len(lists) != 1 else ''))
        if len(pairs) < 40:
            print('\ntuples:')
            for k, t in enumerate(tuples):
                print('({:0.6f}, {:0.6f})    '.format(*t),
                      end='' if k % 4 != 3 else '\n')
            print('\nlists:')
            for k, l in enumerate(lists):
                print('[({:0.6f}, {:0.6f}), ({:0.6f}, {:0.6f})]    '
                      .format(*l.ravel()), end='' if k % 2 != 1 else '\n')
    print('\n\ncomputation time', t0)
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try it as soon as possible!

Comment: I didn't test the code yet, but it seems it splits the original lists. Can you confirm? I want to keep them as a whole

Comment: The code goes through them with a fine toothed comb but it doesn't alter them. It creates new references to the elements of the lists but that doesn't change them. Btw. the code assumes you have them all in one large list of lists, i.e. `lists = [a, b, c, d, e]`.

Comment: I tested the code. It worked, but maybe it's not enough because it groups all the shared tuples for every key, but doesn't "concatenate" them as in my example. :(

Comment: What precisely do you want? For a given tuple (x,y) all the lists containing it fused together into one flat list? with (x,y) repeating?

Comment: Your first code prints: `{(70, 100): [3, 4], (100, 50): [1], (100, 100): [0, 2], (100, 80): [4], (20, 60): [2], (50, 60): [0, 1], (50, 10): [3]}`. For example, the value from the second key should be linked to the tuple at index `0` (i.e. `a = [(100,100), (50,60)]`)because they share a common tuple. I'm sorry, but I don't see the expected result I posted in my question (i.e. a list contained all the "chained" tuples). Or am I wrong? :(

Comment: I added a new code path doing that. Btw. I checked your  example again. I'd say it does what my first version does: A list of list of tuples. Your `newlist1` evaluates to `[[(100, 100), (50, 60)], [(100, 50), (50, 60)], [(100, 100), (20, 60)]]`, for example.

Comment: No, sorry, I'm wrong. I didn't see the chaining! My bad. I'll revise the code. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Don't worry! Instead I really appreciate your help! I know it's a tricky situation (almost for me), so thanks for your efforts!

Comment: I have to go by now, but I'll promise I will go back tomorrow to see if there is any news (I hope)!

Comment: @mgri Hi, if you have a minute why not have a look at the new version and check whether it meets your requirements. I've tested it on your toy example but that's hardly a stress test. Cheers

Comment: Oh my GOD! Did you write a whole software?? Thanks mate! This morning I saw from the mobile a previous solution, so I'll test them both! I'll give you an update!

Comment: Haha, guess I had a point to prove. But don't praise it before you've tested it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get a general error from your last code (I'm not a programmer, so I can't understand well how it works. Maybe it's my fault or I miss some libraries since I'm using a Python interpreter from a GIS software. However, I'll try later to get it working). Instead, the good news is that the previous version should be enough for my purposes, so I can only say: thanks, thanks and thanks! You were a magician for me! All the best!